# Who killed these people?

Tags: ice-fantasy

> Pian Feng and the Bear King

were both killed by a glowing purple assassination spell. I wasn't quite sure who cast it, though.

- Yuan Ji. In favor: he's perfectly willing to kill people, and he often attacks incorporeally. Pian Feng and the Bear King also were described as having his seal on their body because he ripped their souls from their bodies. Against: The spell didn't look like his at all (purple, not black smoke with blue sparks or the blue orange Ice-Fire spell. Why would he kill them but not the others? Maybe being killed by his Guardians puts his seal on a soul.
- Xing Gui: In favor: They were in her territory. Purple is often associated with Dream Clan. Against: She didn't really seem to want to kill them. Would she know an assassination spell?

Which one was it?